# Mongoose Difficulty in displaying time stamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, backend

I have been Recently Working on Mongoose To connect with the MongoDB with Node application.
I have Used Schemas to build the model and set the timestamps to true.
But When i try to run the node application it displays a very long message and the time stamps are empty in the terminal but displays when copied and pasted in text editor.
I want the output to be short to only display the documents available in my collection.
**Here is My code**
**index.js file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Dishes = require('./models/dishes')

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected correctly to server');

    Dishes.create({
        name: 'Uthapizzas',
        description: 'Test'
    })
    .then((dish) => {
        console.log(dish);

        return Dishes.findByIdAndUpdate(dish._id,{
            $set: { description: 'Updated Test'}
        },{
            new: true//return the updated dish
        }).exec();
    })
    .then((dish) => {
        console.log(dish);

        dish.comments.push({
            rating: 5,
            comment: 'I\'m getting a sinking feeling!',
            author: 'Leonardo di Carpaccio'
        });
        return dish.save();
    })
    .then((dish) => {
        console.log(dish);
        return Dishes.remove({});
    })
    .then(() => {
        return mongoose.connection.close();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**dishes.js file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new Schema({
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const dishSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments:[commentSchema]
}, 
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

var Dishes = mongoose.model('Dish', dishSchema);

module.exports = Dishes;
```

**Here is My output**

```
<ref *1> model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: undefined,
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: true,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array],
      map: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    session: null,
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    '$options': {}
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: {
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    name: 'Uthapizzas',
    description: 'Test',
    comments: CoreMongooseArray(0) [
      _path: 'comments',
      toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
      _atomics: {},
      _parent: [Circular *1],
      _cast: [Function: _cast],
      _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
      _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
      '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
      hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
      _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
      push: [Function: push],
      nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
      '$pop': [Function: $pop],
      pop: [Function: pop],
      '$shift': [Function: $shift],
      shift: [Function: shift],
      pull: [Function: pull],
      splice: [Function: splice],
      unshift: [Function: unshift],
      sort: [Function: sort],
      addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
      set: [Function: set],
      toObject: [Function: toObject],
      inspect: [Function: inspect],
      indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
      remove: [Function: pull],
      id: [Function: id],
      create: [Function: create],
      notify: [Function: notify],
      isMongooseDocumentArray: true,
      validators: [],
      _schema: [DocumentArray],
      _handlers: [Object]
    ],
    createdAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.266Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.266Z,
    __v: 0
  }
}
<ref *1> model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: undefined,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    session: undefined,
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, skipDefaults: [Object] }
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: {
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    name: 'Uthapizzas',
    description: 'Updated Test',
    comments: CoreMongooseArray(0) [
      _path: 'comments',
      toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
      _atomics: {},
      _parent: [Circular *1],
      _cast: [Function: _cast],
      _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
      _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
      '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
      hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
      _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
      push: [Function: push],
      nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
      '$pop': [Function: $pop],
      pop: [Function: pop],
      '$shift': [Function: $shift],
      shift: [Function: shift],
      pull: [Function: pull],
      splice: [Function: splice],
      unshift: [Function: unshift],
      sort: [Function: sort],
      addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
      set: [Function: set],
      toObject: [Function: toObject],
      inspect: [Function: inspect],
      indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
      remove: [Function: pull],
      id: [Function: id],
      create: [Function: create],
      notify: [Function: notify],
      isMongooseDocumentArray: true,
      validators: [],
      _schema: [DocumentArray],
      _handlers: [Object]
    ],
    createdAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.266Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.287Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  '$init': true
}
<ref *1> model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: false,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array],
      map: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    pathsToScopes: { comments: [Circular *1] },
    session: undefined,
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, skipDefaults: [Object] }
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: {
    _id: 63563fab8405ad299448f321,
    name: 'Uthapizzas',
    description: 'Updated Test',
    comments: CoreMongooseArray(1) [
      [EmbeddedDocument],
      _path: 'comments',
      toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
      _atomics: {},
      _parent: [Circular *1],
      _cast: [Function: _cast],
      _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
      _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
      '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
      hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
      _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
      push: [Function: push],
      nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
      '$pop': [Function: $pop],
      pop: [Function: pop],
      '$shift': [Function: $shift],
      shift: [Function: shift],
      pull: [Function: pull],
      splice: [Function: splice],
      unshift: [Function: unshift],
      sort: [Function: sort],
      addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
      set: [Function: set],
      toObject: [Function: toObject],
      inspect: [Function: inspect],
      indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
      remove: [Function: pull],
      id: [Function: id],
      create: [Function: create],
      notify: [Function: notify],
      isMongooseDocumentArray: true,
      validators: [],
      _schema: [DocumentArray],
      _handlers: [Object]
    ],
    createdAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.266Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-10-24T07:32:59.308Z,
    __v: 1
  },
  '$init': true
}
```

Can You Please Help me in resolving this issue.
Why i am getting this much lines of output and why my time stamps are not displaying in the output(**They are Displaying when copied**) and the output looks very clumsy.
I only need the output which document i have inserted into the database and need the time stamps.
I am not able to access the time stamps also.
**I am using mongo v5**

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should log your plaing javascript object, not the document. In order to do this, you should call `console.log(dish.toJSON())`.